# Java - Network directory not a file or directory?

Tags: java

Frustrated. This works on a dev box, but not on a production box. This seems to be a problem with permissions but I cannot assume (since the network map is open to everyone and accessible from both machines).

I have a directory in a property file:

- gohere=\\main\sub

In my code, I read the directory correctly from the property file. Here is the code:

```
        File dir = new File(dirFromProperty); // \\\\main\\sub

        System.out.println("dirFromProperty = " + dirFromProperty);
        System.out.println("dir File = " + dir); //looks right
        System.out.println("dir.isDirectory = " + dir.isDirectory()); //false?
        System.out.println("dir.isFile = " + dir.isFile()); //false?!
        System.out.println("dir.isHidden = " + dir.isHidden()); //false

        if(dir.isDirectory()) {
             //never gets here
        }
```

Worth noting:

- This exact code works locally. The minute I run on another server, it fails because it thinks its not a directory. The directory is accessible from both machines 100% confirmed.

Any ideas? I'm going nuts trying to figure out what is going on.

**Edit:**

Right now, it seems this is an issue with Windows Task Scheduler. I can run the application fine from CMD. From the task manager, it does not recognize network paths?

**Second Edit:**

I've added the solution to my problem. This is not Java related, it appears to be related to the Windows task settings and accessing a file via File class in Java.

Comment: It that Windows server? Do you have you dev host in the same network? Could you post the error?

Comment: Can you print your sysouts here?

Comment: So just to confirm, when you go to the other server (where your code fails) and type: DIR \\main\sub at the command-line, you see files?  And you see the same files (or lack thereof) from your local machine?

Comment: Yes - I can take the exact same network path on both servers and see the contents of the directory. No credentials are needed.

Comment: And the sys outs are comments to the right of the code

Comment: Windows 2008 server - Same network.

Comment: Which account do you use to run the task ? Does it have correct permissions ? Temporarily change the task to use your account

Comment: Run it with the same user that you test with - you can specify the account in the scheduled job.  Maybe the account that it is running as does not have network access or has funky permissions.

Comment: Marged - Tried that. Same thing happened. I did read, however, that if I turn off "highest privileges" on the task that it may work. I am going to test it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like Java issue. It's Windows issue. Just substitute your Java program with regular Windows process and you will see the same. Just retrieve and show File/Directory attributes from this process, store them, analyze and you will see the difference from Windows point of view.

My guess would be that Task Scheduler runs under another ID/access which doesn't have appropriate access to this network share. All signs what you describe point to this assumption.

Comment: You are correct. I will mark the answer correct and add information to what fixed this issue. The issue, for some reason, was that I had to eliminate the storing of password with the user (even though the password hasn't changed).

Answer (score 0):

After much digging, I came to the conclusion that the issue had to do with the task itself on the production server.

For some reason, the network pathing was not recognized as a directory by the File class when I used the following setting:

- Run whether user is logged on or not (Check do not store password).

When I unchecked "Do not store password" and allowed it to store the password, the network path was recognized. I assume this is because the network path does require you to be logged into the network (which every server is). I assume this property passed an empty password and thus, no directory.

This is all assumption - but I can 100% confirm it worked when you unchecked store password.